# How to SUM amounts across multiple tables with GROUP BY and ORDER BY?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to reduce these queries to one so it's not three separate queries. Is there a better way to do this other than what I have? I'm also trying to sum all the totals together IE (invoiced_total + refund_total + credit_memo_total). The tables have no relation other than the customer, but I'm not looking to group by customer, just date. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(qbi.amount) AS invoiced_total,
    DATE_FORMAT(qbi.line_item_date, '%Y-%m-01') AS date
        FROM
            invoices as qbi
        WHERE
            qbi.`line_item_date` BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2019-12-31'
        GROUP BY
            DATE_FORMAT(qbi.`line_item_date`, '%Y-%m-01')
         ORDER BY
            DATE_FORMAT(qbi.`line_item_date`, '%Y-%m-01');
SELECT 
    SUM(amount) AS refund_total,
    DATE_FORMAT(refund_date, '%Y-%m-01') AS refund_date
        FROM
            refunds
        WHERE
            refund_date BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2019-12-31'
        GROUP BY
            DATE_FORMAT(refund_date, '%Y-%m-01')
         ORDER BY
            DATE_FORMAT(refund_date, '%Y-%m-01');
SELECT 
    SUM(amount) AS credit_memo_total,
    DATE_FORMAT(credit_memo_date, '%Y-%m-01') AS credit_memo_date
        FROM
            credit_memos
        WHERE
            credit_memo_date BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2019-12-31'
        GROUP BY
            DATE_FORMAT(credit_memo_date, '%Y-%m-01')
         ORDER BY
            DATE_FORMAT(credit_memo_date, '%Y-%m-01');
```

Comment: Can you join the tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to join these queries you must also use a 4th query which will return all the distinct months from the 3 tables just in case there is a month missing in any of them.
This is why you should use left joins for the tables:

```
SELECT d.date, i.invoiced_total, r.refund_total, c.credit_memo_total,
  COALESCE(invoiced_total, 0) + COALESCE(refund_total, 0) + COALESCE(credit_memo_total, 0) AS total
FROM (
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(qbi.`line_item_date`, '%Y-%m-01') AS date FROM invoices UNION
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(refund_date, '%Y-%m-01') FROM refunds UNION
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(credit_memo_date, '%Y-%m-01') FROM credit_memos
) AS d
LEFT JOIN ( 
  SELECT 
    SUM(qbi.amount) AS invoiced_total,
    DATE_FORMAT(qbi.line_item_date, '%Y-%m-01') AS date
        FROM
            invoices as qbi
        WHERE
            qbi.`line_item_date` BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2019-12-31'
        GROUP BY
            DATE_FORMAT(qbi.`line_item_date`, '%Y-%m-01')
) i ON i.date = d.date
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT 
    SUM(amount) AS refund_total,
    DATE_FORMAT(refund_date, '%Y-%m-01') AS refund_date
        FROM
            refunds
        WHERE
            refund_date BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2019-12-31'
        GROUP BY
            DATE_FORMAT(refund_date, '%Y-%m-01')
) r ON r.date = d.date
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT 
    SUM(amount) AS credit_memo_total,
    DATE_FORMAT(credit_memo_date, '%Y-%m-01') AS credit_memo_date
        FROM
            credit_memos
        WHERE
            credit_memo_date BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2019-12-31'
        GROUP BY
            DATE_FORMAT(credit_memo_date, '%Y-%m-01')
) c ON c.date = d.date
WHERE d.date BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2019-12-31'
ORDER BY d.date
```

Comment: @Chris you can remove all the ORDER BY clauses from each of the 3 subqueries, as they are useless. The final sorting will be done at the end of the joins. I will also edit my answer.

Comment: feels unnecessary to use 4th query to grab distinct months since all three queries already return dates that you can use to join each other.

Comment: @iliak *all three queries already return dates that you can use to join each other* how do you know that? What if a month is missing in any of the 3 tables?

Answer (score 0):

You would typically join the three queries. Assuming that all monthes are available in three tables, you could do:

```
SELECT
    i.invoice_month my_month,
    i.invoiced_total,
    r.refund_total,
    c.credit_total,
    i.invoiced_total + r.refund_total + c.credit_total amount_total
FROM (
    SELECT 
        SUM(amount) AS invoiced_total, 
        DATE_FORMAT(line_item_date, '%Y-%m-01') AS invoice_month
    FROM invoices
    WHERE line_item_date BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2019-12-31'
    GROUP BY invoice_month
) i
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        SUM(amount) AS refund_total, 
        DATE_FORMAT(refund_date, '%Y-%m-01') AS refund_month
    FROM refunds
    WHERE refund_date BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2019-12-31'
    GROUP BY refund_month
) r
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        SUM(amount) AS credit_total, 
        DATE_FORMAT(credit_memo_date, '%Y-%m-01') AS credit_month
    FROM credit_memos
    WHERE credit_memo_date BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2019-12-31'
    GROUP BY credit_memo_month
) c
ORDER BY i.invoice_month
```

Side note: in MySQL you can use column aliases in the `GROUP BY` clause (and in the `ORDER BY` clause): this helps shortening the query.